# How to use response.css() with response.follow() for pagination for the last page in Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Here is my code for pagination from first to last page:

```
    url = response.css("li.next a::attr(href)").extract_first()
    if url:
        url = response.urljoin(url)
        yield response.follow(url, self.parse)
```

Scrapy 1.4 [release notes](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html) has another way for it:

```
for a in response.css('li.page a'):
    yield response.follow(a, self.parse)
```

I tried this:

```
    url = response.css("li.next a")[0]
    if url:
        yield response.follow(url, self.parse)
```

But I got error "IndexError: list index out of range" in the last page which I can handle with try, except, else:

```
    try:
        url = response.css("li.next a")[0]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    else:
        yield response.follow(url, self.parse)
```

I'm asking if there is a better and shorter way to solve this or should I stick to old response.url() way for pagination? I'm asking this because I saw this in their release notes, in bold, "it is now a recommended way to create Requests in Scrapy spiders".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the release note way?

```
for a in response.css('li.next a'):
    yield response.follow(a, self.parse)

    # if more than one next can be found and you just need the first
    # break
```

- If there is no element with given selector, the loop will not be activated
- If there is next element, it can be executed by yield.
- The last break is used to handle page contains more than one next element.